# Nested tree element number

Tags: math, tree, logic

What I want to ask is mathematical/logical situation
I have nested tree which looks similar to
[image: this one]

And I need the indexing number of each items order, ex:

```
Tube - 1
LCD -2
Plasma - 3
MP3 Player - 1
CD Player - 2
2 Way Radios -3
```

(1,2,3 ... values are not necessary to be exactly these)

This will be required for ordering the items by this value. After the order I need to get all first items, than all second items... and so on

It is easy to set an order number of each item but what I am looking for is a value calculated from the left-right values of each item and its parent

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Why this restriction on how you compute indices.

Comment: I am guessing the [*Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) tag was used in error and I am removing it.  If I am wrong add it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the index as one plus the index of the left sibling, or as one if there is no left sibling. If you can't control the order in which indices get computed, you might have to iterate over all left siblings, counting them, to compute the index.

There is no direct way. One way to see this is imagining a node being inserted into the tree with a pretty low index. Nodes other than its immediate siblings will have no way of knowing about this insertion, just by looking at parent and direct sibling pointers. But their indices will have to change nonetheless. Which means that these pointers can not be enough to compute indices directly.

Answer (score 0):

To order them, you can use DFS (Depth First Search algorithm). Below is a possible Pseudo-code,

```
DFS(node)
{

index=1

for all child v of node
     assign v the value of index
     DFS (v)
     increment index by 1
end for

}

assign the root the index 1
DFS (root)
```